Why does the throat close up during an allergic reaction?
I was thinking about anaphylaxis and how strange it is that exposure to an allergen, e.g. a peanut, would cause someone’s throat to close up to the point where they can’t breathe. Why does this happen, and then, why would an epinephrine injection stop it?
This page says the histamines cause the throat muscles to contract which blocks the spread. This is more of a molecular answer but I’m thinking why, on a functional level, would this happen?

Remember the requirement to show your own research when posting.
